# How do you compare a single string to a string array

Tags: c++, string-comparison

```
string name;
strarray[] = ["Jack", "Tom" , "Jill"]

if(name == strarray)
{
    //implementation here
}
```

How do I make this comparison work

I am getting an error here because one is a string and one is an array string.

Comment: What do you expect to come out of the comparison?

Comment: What does it mean (in your mind) for a string to be equal to an array of strings?

Comment: Do you wand to see if the string name is an element of the array? Or do you want to combine all the strings in strarray and see if they're equal to name? You're comparing two different things, they'll never be "equal" in the strict sense (unless maybe you had an array with only one string in it).

Comment: I want to compare the name with each individual element in the string. For example, if name equals in single element in the array then the implementation will occur. It only needs to match one element in the array.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library has a function called `find` that does exactly this: (include the `<algorithm>` header)

```
std::string strarray[] = {"Jack", "Tom" , "Jill"};

if (std::find(strarray, strarray + 3, name) != strarray + 3) {
    // implementation here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::find()`:

```
if (std::end(strarray) != std::find(std::begin(strarray), std::end(strarray), name)) {
    // implementation goes here
}
```

`std::begin()` and `std::end()` are new in C++ 2011 but they are trivial to implement:

```
template <typename T, int Size> T* begin(T (&array)[Size]) { return array; }
template <typename T, int Size> T* end(T (&array)[Size]) { return array + Size; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool flag=false;
string name;
strarray[] = ["Jack", "Tom" , "Jill"]

//How do I make this comparison work
//I am getting an error here bc one is a string and one is an array string
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    if(name == strarray[i])
    {
        flag=true;
        break;
    }
}

if(flag)
//implementation here :)
```

Comment: If this is what he's going for, then use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) i.e. `if (std::find(strarray, strarray + 3, name) != strarray + 3) { /* implementation here */ }`